# Drove my chevy to the levee but the levee was dry

Tags: meaning, etymology

Years ago, I heard this phrase (I don't know if it really is a phrase, please correct me if I'm wrong) during a congress from the general manager of a major car production company, but I don't remember the context. What is the meaning and etymology of it?

Comment: It is a line from the song *[American pie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pie_%28song%29)* by Don McLean. It is -- I believe -- a song about the death of John Lennon.

Comment: And a little more, I believe.

Comment: It's a mistranscription of [levee](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/levee), being *an embankment raised to prevent a river from overflowing*. A levy is a tax - which could hardly be dry, even if you could drive to it.

Comment: I know that song but still don't know what this phrase means.

Comment: song lyrics are off-topic.

Comment: @TLP  It's a song about the plane crash in which Buddy Holly ("Peggy Sue","That'll Be The Day", etc.), Ritchie Valens ("La Bamba"), and the Big Bopper ("Chantilly Lace") died.

Comment: @Phoenix So it is. It also predates Lennon's death by 9 years. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm not necessarily asking about a song's lyrics. I heard this from a GM during a congress.

Comment: I found this question easily searchable on Google.

Comment: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/908/what-is-don-mcleans-song-american-pie-all-about

Comment: @iterationx: But that link specifically *doesn't* explain *Drove my chevy to the levee*. Except to say maybe it's just rhyme, which is common enough in lyrics. Anyway, EL&U is hardly the place to decode this particular song, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The line occurs in Don McLean's song *American Pie*. *Chevy* is a Chevrolet motor car and a *levy* (usually spelled *levee*) is a pier or quay. It was dry because there was no water where there should have been. Those more steeped than I in American culture can perhaps tell us the metaphorical meaning.

Comment: The metaphorical meaning probably is no more than levee rhyming with Chevy.  I think that in most of the U.S. 'levee' connotes a miles-long embankment instead of a landing.  Teenagers will drive along on top the levee, or park on top of it and look out across the water at night.

Comment: Don McLean was known to be mysterious with his lyrics... He wouldn't openly disclose what any of American Pie meant.  And the parts of the song that people have figured out are incredibly esoteric and specific to the sign of the times that he wrote it.

Comment: @Rikon That agrees with info at iterationx's link, http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/908/what-is-don-mcleans-song-american-pie-all-about, which also comments (re "three men I admire most..." section): "it simply rhymes, a big determinant of plot direction in pop music lyrics (which may also explain "drove my Chevy to the levee")".